# Magento 2 - Auto login with specific URL

Tags: magento2, customer, login

I have a custom module, I want to auto login a customer on it when the customer comes with an specific url like:

> www.example.com/myModule/?k=2sadf23wasdfde3wefsd34ss43545sdgasdfg/

I have the email address stored in the database against the key that is in URL string.

How can I auto login that particular customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom module, create following files.

> etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="vendor_module" frontName="vendor_module">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $customerCollection;
    protected $customerModel;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerCollection,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerModel,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->customerCollection = $customerCollection;
        $this->customerModel = $customerModel;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $k = $this->getRequest()->getParam('k');

        if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn())
        {
            $collection = $this->customerCollection->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', $k);
            if($collection->getSize())
            {
                $customer_id = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
                $customer = $this->customerModel->create()->load($customer_id);
                $this->customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
                $this->_redirect('customer/account/index');
                return;
            }
        }

        die('customer not found');
    }
}
```

Comment: The code `$this->customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);` worked for me. Thanks :)